# Plural of "today"?

Tags: is-it-a-word

Does the word "today" have a plural form?

I believe it is todays but the gf doesn't believe that is a word?

Thanks

Comment: Report what you found in dictionaries for your question.

Comment: "*In time, all of my **todays' tomorrows** will become my **tomorrows' yesterdays**."*

Comment: https://www.musixmatch.com/lyrics/Bobby-Vinton/All-My-Todays

Comment: Please note, to prevent landing in hot water someday: it is generally considered more respectful to say "my gf" not "the gf."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, the count noun *today* is a word. Take this example:

> " More, " Whistling Pete murmured, drifting in the depths of oceans much deeper than sleep. " More yesterdays. More **todays**. More tomorrows. " (Scott Bradfield. "Penguins for Lunch." Triquarterly 93, 1995 (Spring), p. 21-45; found via [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/))

Or this:

> She faces the additional problem of obtaining the residence registration cards that are required of all Chinese for the youngsters who have no family background. # " I have given the children their **todays**, " she reflects. " But I'm not sure of their tomorrows. " ("A Caring Mother Gives a Home to Chinese Orphans." Christian Science Monitor, 16 Nov. 1994.)

The usage is far rarer - it requires *today* to function as a noun and for the situation to call for referring to multiples of something that normally happens one at a time (*today*, as in *this day*). Yet, it can and does happen.

Comment: Thanks for this. Much appreciated